# The program crashes after reading the first scanf (int type) when it enters a "while"

Tags: c, struct

I am a student and I am having problems with the following code:

The objective is to store data of some patients stored in a txt file and show it on the screen. I have used 2 functions in order to do this, which are "read_patient_data" to store the info in a vector named "patient" which has a type defined by myself. Then I want to show the info on the screen using the "write_patient_data" on the screen.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX_NAME 35
#define MAX_PATIENTS 100

typedef struct
{
    short day, month, year;
}day_entrance;

typedef struct
{
    char character;
    int number;
{identifier;

typedef struct
{
    char name[MAX_NAME];
    identifier IDENTIFIER;
    day_entrance entrance;
    char disease[MAX_NAME];
}patient_t;

void read_patient_data(patient_t *patient, int counter, FILE *p)
{
    short i;
    char character_t;
    i=0;
    character_t=getc(p);
    while (character_t!=' ')
    {
        patient[counter].name[i]=character_t;
        i=i+1;
        character_t=getc(p);
    }
    patient[counter].entrance.day=getc(p);
    patient[counter].entrance.month=getc(p);
    patient[counter].entrance.year=getc(p);
    patient[counter].IDENTIFIER.number=getc(p);
    patient[counter].IDENTIFIER.character=getc(p);
    i=0;
    character_t=getc(p);
    while (character_t!=' ')
    {
        patient[counter].disease[i]=character_t;
        i=i+1;
        character_t=getc(p);
    }


Void write_patient_data(patient_t *patient, int counter, FILE *p)
{
    short i;
    char character_t;
    i=0;
    character_t=patient[counter].name[i];
    while (character_t!=' ')
    {
        printf(&patient[counter].name[i]);
        i=i+1;
        character_t=patient[counter].name[i];
    }
    printf(&patient[counter].entrance.day);
    printf("/");
    printf(&patient[counter].entrance.month);
    printf("/");
    printf(&patient[counter].entrance.year);
    printf("  ");
    printf(&patient[counter].IDENTIFIER.number);
    printf(" - ");
    printf(&patient[counter].IDENTIFIER.character);
    printf("  ");
    i=0;
    character_t=patient[counter].disease[i];
    while (patient[counter].disease[i]!=' ')
    {
        printf(&patient[counter].disease[i]);
        i=i+1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    patient_t patient[MAX_PATIENTS];
    short counter, num_patients;
    counter=0;
    printf("What is the number of patients?");
    scanf("%hi",&num_patients);
    FILE *p;
    p=fopen("pacients.txt","r");
    while (counter<num_patients)
    {
        read_patient_data(&patient, counter, &p);
        counter++;
    }
    counter=0;
    while (counter<num_patients)
    {
        write_patient_data(&patient, counter, &p);
        counter++;
    }
    fclose(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please indent your code so that it is easier to comprehend.  Also, please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  I don't think what you've provided is really minimal.

Comment: This can't be the actual code-- it won't compile. There is a typo in `Void`, and the brace in `{identifier;` appears to be reversed. Proper code indentation would help.

Comment: Please post the contents of `pacients.txt` and fix your struct `typedef struct {
    char character;
    int number;
} identifier;`

Comment: `read_patient_data(&patient, counter, &p);` --> `read_patient_data(&patient, counter, p);`

Comment: You shouldn't try to run code when your compiler is giving you type mismatch warnings.  You shouldn't post code that doesn't compile without warnings unless you are asking about what the warnings mean.  If the compiler warns you, it means there's a bug in your code and it knows you will be unhappy with result of it doing what you told it to do.  You're passing a `patient_t (*)[]` (pointer to array) to functions that expect a `patient_t`.  This leads to confusion.  Either drop the `&` in the calls, or pass `&patient[counter]` and make other more dramatic changes in the functions.

Comment: there is a bracket error if I am correct, near the second structure.

Answer (score 2):

This answer builds on some assumption but I hope it can help you anyway.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_NAME 35
#define MAX_PATIENTS 100

typedef struct {
    short day, month, year;
} day_entrance;

typedef struct {
    char character;
    int number;
} identifier;

typedef struct {
    char name[MAX_NAME];
    identifier IDENTIFIER;
    day_entrance entrance;
    char disease[MAX_NAME];
} patient_t;

void read_patient_data(patient_t *patient, int counter, FILE *p) {
    short i;
    char character_t;
    i = 0;
    character_t = getc(p);
    while (character_t != ' ') {
        patient[counter].name[i] = character_t;
        i = i + 1;
        character_t = getc(p);
    }
    patient[counter].name[i] = '\0';
    fscanf (p, "%hd", &patient[counter].entrance.day);
    fscanf (p, "%hd", &patient[counter].entrance.month);
    fscanf (p, "%hd", &patient[counter].entrance.year);
    fscanf (p, "%d", &patient[counter].IDENTIFIER.number);
    fscanf (p, "%c", &patient[counter].IDENTIFIER.character);
    i = 0;
    character_t = getc(p);
    while (character_t != '\n') {
        patient[counter].disease[i] = character_t;
        i = i + 1;
        character_t = getc(p);
    }
    patient[counter].disease[i] = '\0';
}

void write_patient_data(patient_t *patient, int counter, FILE *p) {
    short i;
    fprintf(p, "%s",patient[counter].name);
    fprintf(p, "%hd", patient[counter].entrance.day);
    fprintf(p, "/");
    fprintf(p, "%hd", patient[counter].entrance.month);
    fprintf(p, "/");
    fprintf(p, "%hd", patient[counter].entrance.year);
    fprintf(p, "  ");
    fprintf(p, "%hd", patient[counter].IDENTIFIER.number);
    fprintf(p, " - ");
    fprintf(p, &patient[counter].IDENTIFIER.character);
    fprintf(p, "  ");
    fprintf(p, "%s\n", patient[counter].disease);
}

int main() {
    patient_t patient[MAX_PATIENTS];
    short counter, num_patients;
    counter = 0;
    printf("What is the number of patients?");
    scanf("%hi", &num_patients);
    FILE *p;
    p = fopen("pacients.txt", "r");
    while (counter < num_patients) {
        read_patient_data(patient, counter, p);
        counter++;
    }
    counter = 0;
    while (counter < num_patients) {
        write_patient_data(patient, counter, stdout);
        counter++;
    }
    fclose(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Important is the contents of your file `pacients.txt`. The code above can read a file formatted like this

```
carol 1 2 3 4xflu 
mallory 2 3 4 5xfever
```

Test

```
What is the number of patients?2
carol1/2/3  4 - x  flu 
mallory2/3/4  5 - x  fever
```

You might need to change the code according to your needs.

Comment: at `write_patient_data` Use `fprintf` instead of `printf`. and `printf(&patient[counter].IDENTIFIER.character);` --> `fprintf("%c", patient[counter].IDENTIFIER.character);`

Comment: at `read_patient_data` `patient[counter].name` and `patient[counter].disease` not NUL terminated.

Comment: at `main` `write_patient_data(patient, counter, p);` : `p` --> `stdout` ?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Fixed(?). Please look if you approve. Thank you

Comment: my first commant forgot file-pointer.(>.<)   Also It is better to avoid assigning a variable name `stdout`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Arigatou gozaimasu. I fixed it. I hope it is better now.

Comment: `i = i + 1; patient[counter].name[i] = '\0';` : Remove `i = i + 1;` because already increment `i`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Done(?)

Comment: Also maybe for `disease` : `while (character_t != ' ') {` --> `while (character_t != '\n') {` and `fprintf(p, patient[counter].disease);` --> `fprintf(p, "%s\n", patient[counter].disease);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Fixed(?)

Comment: Happy merry Christmas!